# Eclipse Android Sdk Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I receive the following error when opened in Eclipse.
I updated the sdk manager from.
Please help me!

Error:
**This Android Sdk requires Android developer toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.

Current version is 22.3.0**

---

Plugin Install Error:

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.6.1720515 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.6.1720515)
  Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    ADT XML Overlay 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
    ADT XML Overlay 23.0.6.1720515 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.6.1720515)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.6.1720515 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.6.1720515)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.6.1720515]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [22.3.0.v201310242005-887826]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ADT Package 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.2.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Developer Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.3.0.v201310242005-887826]

Comment: You need to update your Android Dev Toolkit from 22.3.0 to 23.0.0 ...

Comment: You must remove your old sdk and download new one.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Android Dev Toolkit from within Eclipse using: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Directions there as well:

> To install this plugin, please use the Update mechanism from within Eclipse and provide it with the following URL:
>
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
>
> Instructions are available on the ADT Plugin For Eclipse page on the android.com web site.